# Major causes of divide overflow

Tags: linux, overflow

I am trying to run some benchmarks on a CPU simulator and it fails to run them due to the divide overflow. Can anyone tell me what exactly can lead to a divide overflow ?

Answer (score 0):

Divide overflow occurs when the results of the division operation overflow the result.  Here is a stackoverflow article describing how to generate integer divide overflow,

[Causing a divide overflow error (x86)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3892379/causing-a-divide-overflow-error-x86)